# Applet not showing anything

Tags: java, applet

How come this does not print show anything on the Applet? I've tried editing it many times and nothing seems to show. Does anyone know what is happening? I tried to paint but it did not work as well. Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.Applet;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.awt.Color;

public class StartingPoint extends Applet{
    private final int pictureWidth = 1001;  
    private final int pictureHeight = 50;
    private static FormCanvas picture;
    private JPanel panel;
    private JTextField numLights;
    private JTextField whichLight;
    private JTextField howLong;



    public void lightCreator(){
        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        picture = new FormCanvas();
        panel.add(picture);
        panel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        numLights = new JTextField("Enter Number of lights total", 20);
        whichLight = new JTextField("Enter which lights you want off separated by commas", 30);
        howLong = new JTextField("Interval time", 10);
        panel.add(numLights);
        panel.add(whichLight);
        panel.add(howLong);
        int light = Integer.parseInt(numLights.getText());
        String lights = whichLight.getText();
        int lightsOn[] = new int[light];
        StringTokenizer str = new StringTokenizer(lights, ",");
        int n = 0;
        while(str.hasMoreElements()){
            lightsOn[n] = Integer.parseInt((String)str.nextElement());
            n++;
        }
        add(panel);
    }

    class FormCanvas extends Canvas {
        // this class paints the GUI 

        FormCanvas() {
            setSize(pictureWidth, pictureHeight);
            setBackground(Color.blue);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Problems:

- Why extend Applet instead of JApplet?
- Why mix Swing and AWT components at all (including Canvas)?
- Where is the `lightCreator()` method called?
- If this is an Applet/JApplet, where is your `init()` method override?

Have you gone through the applet tutorials before trying to create and display an applet? If not, that's the first place that I'd start.

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
public void lightCreator(){
```

To:

```
@Override
public void init() {
```

> How come this does not print show anything on the Applet? .. Does anyone know what is happening?

As alluded to in @Hover's 3rd & 4th comments, the `lightCreator` method is never called in that code.  Use instead the applet life-cycle method `init()` and it will be called a single time when the applet is first loaded.

Comment: ..That change will get the code to the point of displaying the next problem.  It has a variety of them..